# Calculus discontinuities question?

Tags: calculus

How would I find all the discontinuities in the following function.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+2,&\text{if }x<-2\\
2,&\text{if }x=-2\\
-x^2+4,&\text{if }-2<x\le 1\\
x+1,&\text{if }1<x\;.
\end{cases}$$

I have found jump discontinuities in $x=-2$ and $x=1$ but I am unsure if those are all the ones there are.

Answer (score 2):

These are the only two, but the discontinuity at $-2$ is a removable discontinuity, not a jump discontinuity: the limits from each side are $0$.

Comment: Oh I did not see that thanks.

Comment: @Fernando: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have found all. Note that on the intervals: $(-\infty, -2)$, $(-2,1)$, and $(1,\infty)$ the function is given by continuous functions. So the only place that the function could be discontinuous is at $-2$ and at $1$.

Note however, that at $-2$ you have
$$
\lim_{x\to -2^-}f(x) = 0\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to -2^+} f(x) = 0.
$$
So here the graph doesn't jump.